# Continuity of probability density function

Tags: probability, statistics

We model a realistic event of everyday life with a **continuos** probability density function.

What information about the probabilities of the event is carried by the fact that the probability density function is a **continuos** function ?

Comment: $P(X=x_i)=0$ for any specific value $x_i$ in the sample space. :)

Answer (score 0):

That the cumulative distribution function $P(X\le X)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure (the [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution) shows the CDF's continuity is insufficient for a continuous distribution).

Comment: Why real events behave like a **continuos** probability density function ?

Comment: @Qwerto Throw a dart at a board. Where *exactly* does it land? What was the probability that would happen?